# Connecting to a network without connecting to the Internet

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, android, tablet

I am setting up a small system for someone and I need to be able to allow tablets to remote into a small file holding server, however one requirement is that the tablets not be able to access the Internet from the network but other devices need to so I have to disable it for each tablet only. Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly which protocol(s) are you talking about when you say "remote into a file holding server"? And will that server be on the local network or somewhere else? Are the tablet and other devices all owned by you (and thus can be preconfigured with special settings), or are some of the devices outside of your control?

Comment: I could find a solution using OpenVPN to setup an internal network with no access to the external world if you wish to go that route, but would require the tablets be running the VPN software if they wish to connect to the file server.

Comment: That can be set up in the router or modem-router of the "small system", if it is capable of doing so (possibly after installing OpenWRT on it). There are a number of ways to do it, e.g. based on the MAC of the tablets if known in advance, or via a second WLAN AP for the tablets.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your network there are a number of ways of accomplishing this - one common way would be to run a second WIFI network - or better - a virtual WIFI network - which is on a different subnet and VLAN, and then use a firewall to limit access based on IP and/or VLAN address.

Another option - though not as secure, and would only work if you control the tablets - would be to use DHCP to assign IP addresses out of a different range for MAC addresses associated with laptops, and then firewall that subnet - or, depending on the LAN, simply not publish a default gateway to the Android devices (this means DNS and the server would need to be on the same subnet).  Of-course, it might be better to reverse this logic and deny everything access save for those known devices you want to route.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to simply remove the gateway IP address.  This will block the tablets from communicating outside of their subnet.  In your tablet's ip address settings, you can delete the ip gateway.  Depending of the tablet manufacturer (iPad/Android), the IP address settings are in different places.

Comment: Can you provide specifics?

Comment: Yes sure.  In your tablet's ip address settings, you can delete the ip gateway.  That's it.

Comment: I wasn't asking for myself.  Improve the quality of your answer

Comment: thank you, I will try this on an android tablet, I tried it on a windows one and I know it did not work, as it stayed on the networks, but it could not ping any other computer on the network either, so I will have to try with android

Comment: @Tyler - Please remember to disconnect and re-connect the wifi after you've made the change.  Please let me know if it works for you.